# loading product into cart problem

Tags: magento-1.9, error, addtocart

When we add a product to cart, the loading icon appears, but stay there indefinitely. 
The item does appear  in the cart if we reload the page, it is kinda like if the icon was set to appear for unlimited time or failed to disappear.
Can you help us ?

**We are on magento 1.9 version**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any third party theme or customize default Magento theme ?
Please do inspect element and check the console and network tab to see if any JavaScript error is causing this issue.